# Finding the domain of a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

'Given the function  $g(x) = \frac{(4 - 4x^2)}{(4x^2 + 3x)}$, find the domain of g(*x*). From what I understand, we take the denominator and solve for *x* such that the equation in the denominator equals zero. The correct answers here are zero (obviously) and -0.75. I was wondering how exactly one would arrive at the number -0.75 given that the equation holds two instances of the variable *x*. Would anyone mind explaining the process to me? Or was this just done by trial and error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4x^2+3x=0 \iff x(4x+3)=0 \iff (x=0$ or $4x+3=0$)